# Speed issue: Creating Series with Deedle/Getting unique values in F#

Tags: f#, deedle

I have used the solution suggested by Tomas Petricek in this question: [Count unique in a Deedle Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164089/count-unique-in-a-deedle-series)

I have done a quick test python python and the solution above. I have slightly modified the function suggested by Tomas to sort the counts in the reverse order to match the output on the Series.count_values() from the Python function.

```
let unique s = 
    s |> Series.groupInto (fun _ v -> v) (fun _ g -> Stats.count g)
      |> Series.sortBy (fun v -> -v)
```

When I execute the following code in F# Interactive

```
let rand = Random()
let l = [|1..1_000_000|] |> Array.map (fun _ -> rand.Next(1000))
                         |> Series.ofValues
                         |> unique
```

And using "#time" I get execution of around 1500ms in average (150ms for just creating the random Series).

I have also tested a similar code (in the Python console of PyCharm using Python 3.7)

```
import time
import pandas
start = time.time()
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(1000000, 1)), columns=list('A'))
a = df['A'].value_counts()
print(a)
print("ms: %", 1000*(time.time()-start))
```

And I get, for the creation of the DataFrame + value_counts() around 40ms (half half for each step).

Any tip on how, at least, fasten the creation of the Series in F#? My code may not be the most efficient and I would like to know what I could do. I am trying to switch the mood in my team to switch some research from Python to F# and I do not want to hear from them that F# is way to slow. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know neither pandas nor deedle but I suspect the generic aggregation in Deedle don't keep up with a potentially specialized version in pandas (or pandas might just be optimized more thoroughly).

One approach is to perform the counting of values before passing the observations to Deedle.

For example:

```
let rand = Random ()
let variant () = 
  Array.init 1_000_000 (fun _ -> rand.Next(1000))
  |> Array.groupBy id
  |> Array.map (fun (k, vs) -> (k, vs.Length))
  |> Array.sortBy (fun (_, c) -> -c)
  |> Series.ofObservations
```

When comparing the original code with variant above it I got the following numbers.

```
Original took: 1197 ms with (60, 30, 11) cc
Variant took: 56 ms with (2, 0, 0) cc
```

So the array variant seemes significantly faster as well as creating less GC pressure.

Full code sample

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Linq

open Deedle

let now =
  let sw = Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  fun () -> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

let time a =
  let inline cc i       = GC.CollectionCount i
  GC.Collect (2, GCCollectionMode.Forced)
  GC.WaitForFullGCComplete () |> ignore
  let before            = now ()
  let bcc0, bcc1, bcc2  = cc 0, cc 1, cc 2
  let v                 = a ()
  let acc0, acc1, acc2  = cc 0, cc 1, cc 2
  let after             = now ()
  v, after - before, (acc0 - bcc0, acc1 - bcc1, acc2 - bcc2)

let seed = 982301576

let run () =
  let rand = Random seed
  let original () = 
    [|1..1_000_000|] 
    |> Array.map (fun _ -> rand.Next(1000))
    |> Series.ofValues
    |> Series.groupInto (fun _ v -> v) (fun _ g -> Stats.count g)
    |> Series.sortBy (fun v -> -v)

  let _, ms, cc = time original
  printfn "Original took: %d ms with %A cc" ms cc

  let rand = Random seed
  let variant () = 
    Array.init 1_000_000 (fun _ -> rand.Next(1000))
    |> Array.groupBy id
    |> Array.map (fun (k, vs) -> (k, vs.Length))
    |> Array.sortBy (fun (_, c) -> -c)
    |> Series.ofObservations

  let _, ms, cc = time variant
  printfn "Variant took: %d ms with %A cc" ms cc

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  run ()
  0
```